# Why does $|f(x)| \leq x^2 \implies$ $f$ is differentiable in $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Why does $|f(x)|\leq x^2 \implies$ $f$ is differentiable in $0$?

Here's my proof:

[image]

Comment: It is not quite clear to me why $-f(0)$ should equal $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-x^2-f(0)}x$, other than by the fact that incidentally $\frac{-x^2-f(0)}x=x$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-x^2-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to 0}-x-f(0)=-f(0)$?

Comment: @p Where did the $\frac{-f(0)}x$ go?

Comment: Oh, my mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, $|f(x)|\leq x^2$ implies $f(0) = 0$. Then you can continue with
$$
 \left | \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} \right| = \left | \frac{f(x)}{x} \right| \le |x|
$$
for $x \ne 0$, which implies
$$
f'(0) =  \lim_{x \to 0 }\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = 0 \,.
$$

Answer (score 1):

By the inequality we have that $f(0)=$ so $f'(0)=0$

Do exactly what you did in the proof ans replace $f(0)$ with zero.

So $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=0$